# No route matches [POST] "/ads/create"

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

Ror rookie.

Getting this error -> No route matches [POST] "/ads/create"

Here is the view for ads/new.html.erb

```
    <%= form_for :ad, url:{action: "create" } do |f| %>

    <p>Name: <%= f.text_field :name %><br /></p>
    <p>Description: <%= f.text_area :description %><br /></p>


     <p><%= f.submit "Create this" %></p>
```

Here is the view for ads/create.html.erb

```
    <h1>Record added</h1>
    <p>Have fun</p>
```

Here is the routes file

```
      resources :tickets

      get '/ads/new', to: 'ads#new'
      get '/ads/create', to: 'ads#create'
      get '/ads/', to: 'ads#index'
      get '/ads/:id', to: 'ads#show'
```

Controller

```
    class AdsController < ApplicationController

     def new
       @ad = Ad.new
     end

    def create
       @ad=Ad.new(params[:ad])
       @ad.save
    end

   def show
       @ad = Ad.find(params[:id])

   end

   def index
    @ads = Ad.find(:all)
   end

   end
```

I am using Rails 4.0.0.rc2 and Ruby 1.9.3. Need help badly, can't figure out why I keep getting this error -> No route matches [POST] "/ads/create"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should have:

```
<%= form_for @ad do |f| %>
```

in your view and:

```
resources :ads, only: [:new, :create, :show, :index]
```

in your `routes.rb` to make it working, clear and rails-way.

And you get your error because you define route to `create` action with `GET` http method (which is, by the way, quite bad), but your form uses `POST` method.

Comment: Thanks. I tried it and now I get a new error 

ActiveModel::ForbiddenAttributesError

def create
       @ad=Ad.new(params[:ad])
       @ad.save
end

Do I need to change the controller or is there anything wrong in the syntax?

Comment: @AmitBanerjee This problem is not related to the one in your question. But to solve it, you should make use of [strong params](https://github.com/rails/strong_parameters).

Comment: Not sure what that means and how to use it since I am just taking the baby steps.

Comment: @AmitBanerjee Ask another question and you'll get the answer (don't forget to mark mine or Rahul's answer as accepted).

Answer (score 1):

You have created `get` routes but there isn't any routes for `post` method. Add this in your routes file

```
post '/ads/', to: 'ads#create'
```

Its advisable to follow a RESTful pattern in your routes. So instead of having a `GET /ads/create`, have a 'POST /ads/'. [Rails routing guide](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#crud-verbs-and-actions) is very helpful in understanding REST in rails.

Comment: I tried this but it did not work. Not sure why. Thanks for your answer.